# is it possible that compiled languages (C#, Java) to benefit indentions as a code block indication like python?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages, indentation

I' am curious, *"**indentation as a code block indication**"* is an Intellectual Property of *Python* programming language and other languages such as *C#* and *Java* will not be able to copy it. **OR**, it's technically impossible for these such programming languages which are of type complied to benefit this idea?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing stopping other languages from using indentation to denote blocks, and some other languages do; for example, indentation matters in F♯. Older languages presumably don't do this because it's simpler to parse a block if the syntax has dedicated "begin block" and "end block" tokens (and older parsers are more likely to have been written by hand and had to run on more limited hardware), and other modern languages may choose not to use indentation like this for a variety of reasons.

Note that this is a choice: even if it seems to you that using indentation to denote blocks is simply a superior way to design a language's syntax, you should be aware that many programmers will disagree with you. If a language doesn't use indentation to denote blocks, it's generally not because the language's syntax *couldn't* have been that way, but rather because the language designers chose not to make it that way.

This has nothing to do with whether the language is compiled or interpreted, since parsing occurs before either compilation or interpretation; actually, it is not really correct to say that a *language* is compiled or interpreted, it is more correct to say that an implementation of a language is a compiler or an interpreter, and some languages have both kinds of implementation.

Comment: `simpler to parse a block if the syntax has dedicated "begin block" and "end block" tokens`, you are correct it's much simpler but on the other hand, there is a competition between programming languages which trying to keep their users. using this option as optional case, not only attracts python devs to using C# or Java languages because they will not have hard times adapting to new grammar.

Comment: I do believe that language designers should use other languages valuable ideas unless there is a technical matter which prevents it to be happened.

Comment: @AFarmanbar From my experience of teaching other languages to students who have learned Python first, and according to research on what aspects of learning programming students find difficult, syntax is the easiest part of learning a programming language, and very few students take longer than a session or two to get used to the new language's syntax. (Those who do have trouble with it typically have trouble with a lot more than just the syntax.) So I doubt that a "dual-mode" syntax like you describe would ever outweigh the increased complexity of implementing the language.

Comment: Yes, of course language designers should borrow valuable ideas from existing languages. The point is that just because you perceive value in an idea doesn't mean that other people do; there is value in other languages' syntaxes, too.